# functionality of setting `require_client_auth`

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to set the client to nodes SSL encryption for one of our client.

I have confusion regarding the functionality of setting `require_client_auth` in client_encryption_options in cassandra.yaml and what configuration needs to set from client and cassandra node in case I set require_client_auth to true.

Password authentication is already set,now investigating if there might be any additional advantage to having both ("authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator" and "require_client_auth: true") turned on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Jim stated, `require_client_auth` doesn't have anything to do with Cassandra's auth system.  It is an additional level of security configuration for client-to-node SSL.

When you implement client-to-node SSL *and* enable `require_client_auth` you are enabling what is known as Two Way SSL.  Instead of the Cassandra client simply verifying the identity of the server, the server also verifies the certificate used by the client.  This doc [One Way and Two Way SSL and TLS](https://www.ossmentor.com/2015/03/one-way-and-two-way-ssl-and-tls.html) (Peeples K. 2015) has a good description of this process:

> Two-way SSL authentication is also referred to as client or mutual authentication because the application acting as an SSL client presents its certificate to the SSL server after the SSL server authenticates itself to the SSL client.
>
> Establishing the encrypted channel using certificate-based 2-Way SSL involves:
>   [image: Two Way SSL]
>
> 1. A client requests access to a protected resource.
> 2. The server presents its certificate to the client.
> 3. The client verifies the server’s certificate.
> 4. If successful, the client sends its certificate to the server.
> 5. The server verifies the client’s credentials.
> 6. If successful, the server grants access to the protected resource requested by the client.

On the other hand, with One Way SSL the client only verifies the server's certificate (from the same doc).

[image: One Way SSL]

The advantage of Two Way SSL would be in knowing that the Cassandra nodes will not allow a connection from an unknown client certificate.

IMO, one Way SSL still offers a decent degree of security.  The dev team will need to present a cert which validates up through the same CA (certificate authority) as the cert from the Cassandra nodes.  Two Way SSL might be useful in a large org, helping to keep out connections from applications that have not first talked with your team.

Comment: if I setup one way SSL, shouldn't the connection fail if my cqlshrc file specifies an ip instead of hostname?

Comment: @SledgeHammer Cassandra doesn't use a SSL cert like a website does, so the cert's common name not matching the bind address/URL isn't an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the require_client_auth is for SSL (certificate) communication between the client and server, and that the client must identify itself (you can have it so that the server is the only one that identifies itself).